# Can we fire a traditional join query in spark sql

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have two tables , table1 and table2 .

The query formed is like : `select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id;`

now when we load spark Database connection through this code.How can we mention two tables , such that a join could be fired?

code for reference

```
spark.read().format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename")
    .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    .option("dbtable", "table1")
    .option("user", "root")
    .option("password", "root")
    .load().createOrReplaceTempView("table1");

Dataset<Row> sql = spark.sql("select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id");
```

I have tried above code, but it says `table2 not found`. Hence can the above query be fired from spark sql?

Comment: What is table2 here

Comment: Hi Chandan , you can assume any table2 , with foreign key relation to table1.

Answer (score 2):

In dbtable option you can use your query , but with a alias and load your dataframe.

```
Dataset<Row> load = spark.read().format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/etl_config")
.option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
.option("dbtable", "(select * from forms inner join form_entity on forms.form_id = form_entity.form_parent_id where forms.form_id = 3)tmp")
.option("user", "root")
.option("password", "root")
.load();
```

The above configuration , would be resolved as `select * from tmp where 1=0;`

Answer (score 1):

YES.

Using mysql against a public database and assuming both table are in mysql, here is a snippet that makes little sense, but with a few pointers and a traditional JOIN without inner approach, but none-the-less it demonstrates the point:

```
 val dataframe_mysql = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, s"""(select DISTINCT f1.type as f1_type, f2.type as f2_type from family f1, family f2 where f1.type like '${val1}' ) f """, connectionProperties)
```

You know the rest.

BTW you could use a view in mysql - but I suspect you know that as well.

Comment: Got your point , but I am not sure with the options part in java , what to add , so that it recognizes table2.

Comment: spark.read().format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename")
    .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    .option("dbtable", "table1")
    .option("user", "root")
    .option("password", "root")
    .load().createOrReplaceTempView("table1");

Comment: Where is table2?

Comment: Nothing. There are a couple of approaches. Your approach should follow the s" as listed in other answers. That is older style. I use s" as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got your point.

In dbtable option you can use your query and load your dataframe.

```
spark.read().format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename")
.option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
.option("dbtable", s”select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id")
.option("user", "root")
.option("password", "root")
.load();
```

Make sure the what ever the query passed it should be inline with your database